# Using PHP to calculate Pi

Tags: php, loops, pi

Okay this is just something me and my coworker are playing with.
We know PHP has it's own PI function but this came forth out of a theory and curiosity.

So we were wondering if and how PHP was able to calculate `pi`.
Formule of `pi` =  `π= 4/1 - 4/3 + 4/5 - 4/7 + 4/9...`

Here is what we did:

```
$theValue = 100;// the max
   for ($i=1; $i<$theValue; $i++){
   if ($i % 2 == 1){
       $iWaardes[] =  4 / $i; // divide 4 by all uneven numbers and store them in an array
    }
}
// Use the array's $keys as incrementing numbers to calculate the $values.
for ($a=0, $b=1, $c=2; $a<$theValue; $a+=3, $b+=3, $c+=3 ){
    echo ($iWaardes[$a] - $iWaardes[$b] + $iWaardes[$c]).'<br>';
}
```

So now we have a loop that calculated the first series of `4/1 - 4/3 + 4/5` but it stops after that and starts over with the following 3 sequences.
How can we make it run the entire `$theValue` and calculate the whole series?

Please keep in mind that this is nothing serious and just a fun experiment for us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use one loop. Have a `$bottom` variable that you add 2 on each iteration, divide by it, and add it/subtract it depending on the modulo:

```
$theValue = 10000; // the max
$bottom = 1;
$pi = 0;
for ($i = 1; $i < $theValue; $i++) {
    if ($i % 2 == 1) {
        $pi += 4 / $bottom;
    } else {
        $pi -= 4 / $bottom;
    }
    $bottom += 2;
}
var_dump($pi); // 3.14169266359
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/Q8nZr)

What's wrong with your code (other than not dividing by the appropriate number) is the second loop. You're for some reason printing out the stored numbers 3 by 3. This, until `$a`, that increases by 3, is lower than `$theValue` which is much higher. So, for example, if `$theValue` is 10, you only need 2 loops before you start getting out of bound errors.

Comment: In your code how can I extend the lenght of `pi`? e.g. 3.14169266359xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: @Interactive read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)

Answer (score 4):

You're overthinking this. Just use the modulo to decide if you want to add or subtract and do it in place.

```
$theValue = 100;// the max
$pi = 0;
for ($i=1; $i<$theValue; $i++){
    if ($i % 2 == 1){
        $pi += 4.0 / ($i * 2 - 1);
    } else {
        $pi -= 4.0 / ($i * 2 - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: @interactive about your edit, I didn't get it the first time, sorry. Next time you'll be better served by a comment to the answer :)

Comment: Dude. I just spent 10 minutes looking at a 9 line script and couldn't find the error :-)

Comment: The export shows `3.15169340607` In my world `pi` is `3.14159265359`. Can you see what's wrong?

Comment: Oh wauw. I just found out that when you increse `$theValue` the entire output changes.

Comment: @Interactive that's the point. The series converges towards `pi` the further you go into it.

Answer (score 0):

`pi()` Returns an approximation of pi. The returned float has a precision based on the precision directive in php.ini, which defaults to 14. Also, you can use the M_PI constant which yields identical results to pi()

[source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pi.php)

Using PHP we can also calculate Pi, albeit very slowly.

```
$pi = 4; $top = 4; $bot = 3; $minus = TRUE;
$accuracy = 1000000;

for($i = 0; $i < $accuracy; $i++)
{
  $pi += ( $minus ? -($top/$bot) : ($top/$bot) );
  $minus = ( $minus ? FALSE : TRUE);
  $bot += 2;
}
print "Pi ~=: " . $pi;
```

This method of calculating Pi is slow, but it is easy to read code.
You can read more about this method here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80

If you increase the $accuracy variable, Pi will be calculated more and more accurately. Depending on how fast your web server is, you can calculate the first 6 digits of Pi fairly quickly.

The time it takes to calculate each succeeding number goes up exponentially however. To calculate 20 digits of Pi using this method method could take years.

Comment: You need to give attribution. [Source](https://coderwall.com/p/g35wya/calculating-pi-using-php)